# How to take the response of a SOAP call using PHP with an XML body

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to call a `SOAP` method using `PHP`.

**Here's the code I've got:**

```
$wsdl = 'LINK/RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAO?wsdl';
$options = array('login' => 'MYLOGIN','password' => 'MYPASS');

$xml = <<<EOT
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rhow="http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/RHOWS/RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAO">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <rhow:RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAOInput>
         <rhow:P_IDENTIFICACAO-VARCHAR2-IN>ASDASDADASDA</rhow:P_IDENTIFICACAO-VARCHAR2-IN>
         <rhow:P_RESULT-XMLTYPE-OUT/>
      </rhow:RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAOInput>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
EOT;

//echo $wsdl;   
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```

**Now I would like print the request, but nothing is showing:**

```
    $body = new SoapVar($xml,XSD_ANYXML);
    **$result = $client->RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAO($body);**
    print $client->__getLastRequest()."\n";
    print $client->__getLastResponse()."\n";
```

I put the

```
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

end it´s returns:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(83) "RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAOOutput **RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAO**(RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAOInput $parameters)" }
```

So used the

```
$result = $client->RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAO($body);
```

but northing..

Comment: Please go to your wsdl page with your browser and check the definition for the webservice **RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAO**
I guess you have to call this webservice with a specific type of parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you didn't call a SOAP webservice, you configure a SOAP client with a specific wsdl definition (you could copy wsdl's url into your browser too see the structure. Try this:

```
$client->__getFunctions();
```

To list all function for this wsdl definition

Then call a function available by this way

```
$response = $client->someFunction($foo, $bar);
```

After that you should have a return of this functions, because your soap client really launched a request

```
print $client->__getLastRequest()."\n";
print $client->__getLastResponse()."\n";
```

Comment: I put the  var_dump($client->__getFunctions());  end it´s return me:    array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(83) "RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAOOutput RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAO(RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAOInput $parameters)"
}         So used the $result = $client->RHOWS_RS_REQUISICAO($body); but aren´t showing northing...